# how to fetch html data when it's add dynamic via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#add").click(function()
{
  $("#content").append("<input type=text name=resource>");
})
```

I have to work with dynamically add text box so how fetch those value in php.

Comment: rest of the codes (which you tried)? **AND IT IS NOT A  PHP QUESTION!**

Comment: what do u want i cannot understand..........

Comment: its difficult yo understand u(code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hay it's just resource name as array like 
resource[]

Answer (score 2):

**Jquery Dynamic Adding:**

```
$("#add").on('click',function()
{
  $("#content").append("<input type=text name=resource[] />");
});
```

**PHP Code with Metod POST:**

```
$data =$_POST['resource'];
```

**For Individual Values:**

```
foreach($data as $vals)
{
   echo $vals;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `.live()` for this? There is absolutely no reason to do so and additionally `live` is deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

if php variable available, then you can add that variable inside the append or anywhere likes following

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#content").append("input type=text name=resource value="<?php echo $variable; ?>">);
});
```